# Combining Flask's run loop with IBAPI (TWSAPI)'s run loop

Tags: loops, rest, flask

I am trying to build a microservice using python that accepts HTTP requests and then sends it to the IBAPI (Interactive Broker; stocks). I was wondering how to get the loop for the IBAPI client running while also keep the flask service running.

A basic Flask program looks like:

```
import json
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def query_records():
    name = request.args.get('stock_id')
    # ...
    # I want to send out a request which response will be process by the client's run method (possibly in a separate thread)
 
    app.reqMktData(reqId, contract2, "", True, False, [])
    app.evAllDone.wait() # set by IBAPI's client's callback (via its run method)
    
app.run(debug=True)
```

IBAPI client's run is implemented like:

```
    def run(self):
        """This is the function that has the message loop."""

        try:
            while self.isConnected() or not self.msg_queue.empty():
                try:
                    try:
                        text = self.msg_queue.get(block=True, timeout=0.2)
                        if len(text) > MAX_MSG_LEN:
                            self.wrapper.error(NO_VALID_ID, BAD_LENGTH.code(),
                                "%s:%d:%s" % (BAD_LENGTH.msg(), len(text), text))
                            break
                    except queue.Empty:
                        logger.debug("queue.get: empty")
                        self.msgLoopTmo()
                    else:
                        fields = comm.read_fields(text)
                        logger.debug("fields %s", fields)
                        self.decoder.interpret(fields)
                        self.msgLoopRec()
                except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
                    logger.info("detected KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit")
                    self.keyboardInterrupt()
                    self.keyboardInterruptHard()
                except BadMessage:
                    logger.info("BadMessage")

                logger.debug("conn:%d queue.sz:%d",
                             self.isConnected(),
                             self.msg_queue.qsize())
        finally:
            self.disconnect()
```

I was thinking about something like the following, but then I got stuck. How can I combine two 'endless' (looping) run functions? At least, I assume there is also a endless run loop for Flask.

```
class BasicApp(EWrapper, EClient, Flask):
  pendingEnds = None
  pendingLock = None
  evAllDone = None
  #...

  def __init__(self,import_name):
    EClient.__init__(self,self)    
    Flask.__init__(self,import_name)
    #...
    self.evAllDone = threading.Event()  # proceed when all stocks are received. if completed then the HTTP response will be given. may take some time.

    # Connect to TWS API
    self.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 0)
    
    thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run) # new callback thread
    thread.start()
    setattr(self, "_thread", thread)`
```

I read something about initialization before entering (and cleanup after finishing) the Flask loop:

```
app_context()
```

(should IBAPI client's connection be made and it's run method be started in a thread here?)

```
teardown_appcontext
```

(finshing and calling thread's join()?)

Would this be a good idea? Or should I consider other APIs like grpc, pyms or fastapi?